# Help needed with solving MIPS jump instruction encoding question

Tags: assembly, mips, encoding, hex

I am currently working on a project that involves understanding the encoding of MIPS assembly instructions and I am struggling with a question that I hope someone here can help me with.

The question is as follows:

"Assume that the MIPS machine encoded word of the following instruction is located at address 0x00400008 in the program code memory.
j foo
Assume further that label foo is located at address 0x00400024. What is then the machine encoding of the jump instruction? Include a short explanation of the different parts of encoding."

My attempt at solving this question is:

0x08000000 | ((0x00400024 >> 2) & 0x03FFFFFF)

This machine encoding is a 32-bit word, with the first 6 bits (0x08) representing the opcode for the "j" instruction, and the remaining 26 bits representing the jump target address.

The opcode (0x08) is the binary representation of the instruction and it tells the CPU that this instruction is a jump instruction.

The jump target address (0x03FFFFFF) is the address where we want to jump to in the program.

So the final machine encoded word for the instruction is: 0x083FFFFF

I believe that this is the correct way to solve the question but I am not entirely sure. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could review my solution and let me know if I am on the right track or if there are any mistakes.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is a pure programming question and would be much better sutured for stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to start explaining or what to say or suggest, after seeing a mask itself being forthrightly encoded into the instruction.

Comment: Additional to Marcus' comment, you might want to add a citation and/or URL of the programmer's manual for MIPS that backs up your solution. And what makes you unsure? (Hint: You did not execute the shift and AND operations.)